# Clickhouse deleting data with WHERE

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I am trying to delete some data using WHERE, note that I need 2 tables in order to identify the rows that should be deleted, so I need to join them, I thought of something like:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_db.test_first_table DELETE WHERE
    (
        SELECT s.value
        FROM sample_db.test_first_table ft
   
        JOIN sample_db.test_second_table st ON (ft.value=st.value)
        
        WHERE `EXPRESSION HERE`
    )
```

I understood that this Alter operation is a [mutation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/#mutations), so when checking `system.mutations` table I see there is this fail reason: `Code: 125, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Scalar subquery returned more than one row`

I checked that the expression I am writing is fine with a simple SELECT statement, so I am out of ideas how I can delete multiple rows based on an expression, any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

First of all: MUTATIONS are admin operations. They cannot be used on daily bases.

```sql
ALTER TABLE sample_db.test_first_table DELETE WHERE 
  value in 
     (  SELECT value
        from sample_db.test_second_table
        WHERE `EXPRESSION HERE`
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just want to update it once to clean up some old data. Basically I want to delete everything that the select query returns, so I' thinking `value in` line is not needed, just not sure how to formulate it.